# Obtain user-friendly monitor name from IDXGIOutput1

Tags: windows, directx

I've got an `IDXGIOutput1` that refers to a display output. However, I can't seem to find the means to turn this into the monitor's user-facing name that you can see in, say, Screen Resolution (I'm on Windows 7). So far I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847028/298661) answer (and checked a couple of the other WMI properties referenced) and the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15746286/298661) question and answer. But the best I've gotten back so far is "Generic PnP Monitor". The name my Screen Resolution gives is stuff like "Acer V243H".

Comment: I have two monitors - one from Dell and one from ASUS.  The Dell one reports itself fine, correct model number, entries in the registry, etc.  I suspect either of the two answers you linked above would show the correct string for this monitor.  The ASUS on the other hand shows "Generic PnP Monitor" *everywhere* except the Screen Resolution UI.  Unfortunately, I can't find the model string anywhere in the registry, and the only place I find it in any file on my system is in some obscure app compat directory.  You may be out of luck finding a reliable way to get this string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EDID (Extended Display Identification Data) of each monitor to get the vendor and model of each monitor.  This is where the OS gets all the information for each monitor attached to the system.

You can follow this article that explains how to get the EDID data structure in Windows 7: [Win32 code to get EDID in Windows XP/7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363699/win32-code-to-get-edid-in-windows-xp-7)

Then based on the [EDID format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data#EDID_1.3_data_format) the information you are looking for will be in one of the descriptor blocks between offset 54 and 125.

The [EDID Manager](http://www.extron.com/download/software.aspx?material=2&id=E) tool might help you traverse EDIDs in a nice GUI so you can see exactly where the information you need is located in the EDID structure.